# When to use “make” versus when to use “do”

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I have trouble choosing between *make* and *do* in a sentence. Could someone please explain them to me?

Comment: If you are an English Language Learner — someone whose first language is ***not*** English — who’s looking for the sort of thing an ESL student needs in this regard, then I hazard that you would probably do better on [the English Language Learners StackExchange site](http://ell.stackexchange.com). In contrast, if you are looking for a seven-page discourse by a linguistics professor on the idiosyncrasies of these two verbs in contemporary and historical English and their cognates in neighboring tongues, then you’ve come to the right place — but your question is too brief.

Comment: Alessio, this is a question that you could ask on our new proposal English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). Please, take a look. Thank you. (Downvote is not mine)

Comment: Alessio, welcome to ELU. As I said earlier, this site is likely geared toward a different set of questions than this one. But I would like to remark that your question is a fairly common one coming from speakers of Romance languages who are learning English. That’s because there’s no pair of verbs in those languages that correspond in a one-to-one fashion to English *make* and *do*. Rather, there is for the most part just one single verb — like IT *fare*, FR *faire*, PT *fazer*, ES *hacer*. But English *make* and *do* each have many special properties beyond even those, too much to write here.

Comment: I agree that this is an excellent question for ELL. To stay here, it needs much more context and a much more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker of English (no linguist), I can give a simple answer:

1. "Make" usually denotes creation of a "new" product or result. 
   Examples: Mother will make dinner. The accident made a lot of noise. Don't make me angry! 
   Exceptions seem to be in informal uses of "make": How did you make out? (This usage means to ask about the quality of one's experience or level of success.) He's on the make. ([This is an idiomatic usage](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=on%20the%20make))
2. "Do" is used to denote engagement in a specific task; the product or result (if any) is less important than engagement in the task. 
   Examples: The student must do the homework. My husband hates to do laundry. I have nothing to do this evening.
   Informal usages: The killer did him in with an ax (murdered). He wants to do her (have intercourse).

Hope this helps.